# Using .getAttribute in a loop to add styles

Tags: javascript, loops, getattribute

First post on here. Hoping someone can help?!

I'm trying to add styles to a parallax carousel I've created by adding data-attributes in the HTML and then looping through each of the images, in the carousel, using JS. I'm able to get the 'data-background' added to the inline styles but the 'data-position' isn't.

Expected output

```
<div class="parallax-container parallax-scale" 
data-background="//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/animage.jpg" 
data-position="50% 50%" data-swiper-parallax="1130.25" 
style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); background-image: url("//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/animage.jpg"); background-position: 50% 50%;">
```

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('parallax-container');

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  var src = list[i].getAttribute('data-background');
  list[i].style.backgroundImage = "url('" + src + "')";
  var pos = list[i].getAttribute('data-position');
  list[i].style.backgroundPosition = pos;
  console.log(list[i])
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax-container parallax-scale" data-background="//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/animage.jpg" data-position="50% 50%">
```

Comment: I made a snippet. Please remove PHP and post only clean HTML and Script

Comment: How do you expect `data-position="50% 50%"` to become `data-position="center center"` ?

Comment: Can you use the [Inspector tab of a web browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_CSS#Examine_CSS_rules) to look, whether the Style is invalid (striked through).

Since you're using data-* attributes, you can use the [dataset property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset), too.

The script looks valid.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've amended mplungjan's snippet to reflect what the expected output should be versus what Is actually happening. Sorry for the typo in the data-position attribute. The background-position inline style should output whatever is input into the data-position attribute.

Comment: Thanks Ryuno-Ki. Have tried with dataset and have no errors in the console...